# Create a non clustered index on SQL Server production table without locking read and insert in offline mode

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014

Considering a table of several millions of rows regularly queried by users and having insert constantly produced by a back-end software.

Is there a way to add a new non-clustered index to this table on a datetime datatype without locking the `INSERT` and `SELECT` from the users while keeping the index in offline mode?

The goal is that this table should always be accessible to users and back-end.

I know operations on existing indexes requires the index operations to be online to prevent locks but if a non clustered index is only being created, would the offline mode still query a table lock and therefore lock the `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements?

Comment: Do you have the enterprise edition of SQL Server ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not, I would understand that using the enterprise edition would allow online operation on index and remove most concerns regarding locking the table. However, while using offline mode in the specific operation of the creation of a non-clustered index, would the table lock still be required and therefore locking insert and read?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create non-clustered indexes offline, you can't can’t minimize the impact as table locks are applied for the duration of the index creation. The only alternative is create an copy of the table with the new index and copy the data. If the table is continuously updated, you can add triggers to keep both tables in sync. During the final deployment you can then drop the triggers and rename the tables inside a transaction. This will still lock the table during the rename, however, the rename is very quick, and the resulting locking should be minimal.